# Creating LAN Chat application using Leetsocket (C#)

Tags: c#

I am using leetsokcet in developing a LAN chat application and I have already finished creating server and client how ever I cannot send message from one PC to another. what's the problem with my code? Is there any settings I need to configure in order to send message from one pc to another pc?? thanks

Comment: if you would post your code, here , it would increase you chance to get some help....

Comment: this says it does it in 5 mins http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tm2jS6mQjRs

Answer (score 2):

If your program works when they're both on the same computer I would guess that you need to open the specific port that you use to send your messages. If you're using windows 7 for instance, this would be done by using the windows firewall configuration.

Comment: thank you for your answer..yes my program works when they're both on the same computer but doesn't work when i used 2 computers. so should i disable the firewall?? or is there any other thing that i should configure??

Comment: Easiest is to just disable the firewall between the two computers but that's insanely unsafe. Find out what port you are using and open the specific ports in the windows firewall configuration. You can google this.